# sql 2005 grouping data that is dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have data that looks like this

```
Investor    Contact
IBM           James  
IBM           Dean  
IBM           Sean  
Microsoft     Bill  
Microsoft     Steve
```

I need the data to look like this

```
Investor     Contact
IBM          James,Dean,Sean  
Microsoft    Bill,Steve
```

OR if the above is impossible

```
Investor        Contact1  Contact2   Contact3  ...
IBM             James      Dean        Sean  
Microsoft        Bill      Steve
```

Comment: See http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/07/06/871.aspx

Comment: Were you using MySQL, the answer would be GROUP_CONCAT().  Since you aren't, you need an equivalent.  See [SO 2852892](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access) and [SO 3389347](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389347/ssrs-group-concat-equivalent-using-an-expression)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Have to know about GROUP_CONCAT to look for it, but [this question also fits the bill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT Investor, 
STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + convert(nvarchar(50), Contact) 
    FROM Investors I2
    WHERE I2.Investor = I1.Investor
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') Contacts
FROM Investors I1
GROUP BY Investor
```

And result in:

```
IBM       James,Dean,Sean
Microsoft   Bill,Steve
```

Comment: Amazing but how does it work?! Any chance you could explain this. I don't want to copy paste...ya know?

Comment: I think this article covers it better than I could:  http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/.  Basically, XML PATH merges the strings together, and then STUFF trims off the leading comma.

Comment: On second thoughts, looking closer at this my row seems to have duplicated a lot of the contacts. So it says Joe, Billy, James, Joe, Billy James, etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: I added select distinct in the inner select...seems to fixed that issue. Still verifying the data. Will post as Answer once I've checked 100%. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try the method below to get your comma separated list going.  I'm going to have to play with it some more to figure out how to get the grouping working.

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' , '') + Contact
FROM InvestorContact
SELECT @listStr
```

Comment: Any more with this? I'd love to see some more about how this fits with grouping. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case any of your contacts have special XML characters in their names: [the Tony Rogerson approach](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/07/06/871.aspx).

```
;with data as
(
SELECT 'IBM' Investor,  'James' Contact UNION ALL  
SELECT 'IBM' ,          'Dean'  Contact UNION ALL  
SELECT 'IBM' ,          'Sean'  Contact UNION ALL  
SELECT 'Microsoft' ,    'Bill'  Contact UNION ALL    
SELECT 'Microsoft',     'Steve' Contact
)
SELECT Investor, 
   stuff((SELECT mydata
   FROM (
      SELECT ',' + Contact  AS [data()]
      FROM
      data AS d2
      WHERE d2.Investor = d1.Investor
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
   ) AS d ( mydata ) FOR XML RAW, TYPE ).value( '/row[1]/mydata[1]', 'varchar(max)' )
, 1, 1, '')
FROM data d1
GROUP BY Investor
```

Comment: The subtree cost when I test with a table is atrocious - 2.49187

Comment: @OMG - But `Bill & Ben` don't become `Bill &amp; Ben`! I haven't tested performance of it. The subtree cost is just a heuristic and doesn't necessarily reflect actual performance - As this shows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424650/sql-query-pervious-row-optimisation/3426364#3426364

Comment: Yeah, `FOR XML PATH` does have the issue with special characters.