# how to convert table row to split by comma by duplicate value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Like below

[image]

I want to separate the column by comma if the "StartDate" Field is same like below

```
EmpID OtherReportID Status StartDate
371    2,381,2       0     2013-11-05 17:59:00:000
371     381          0     2013-11-08 17:59:00:000
371      2           0     2013-11-10 17:59:00:000
371     381          0     2014-08-15 00:00:00:000
```

I tried the below code, just put the number if it is same

```
select DENSE_RANK() over(order by startdate) dd,* from Emp_tb_Eob_OtherReportingManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the equivalent of a `group_concat()` in MySQL.

Please look at this: [How to make a query with group_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: What is not working on SQL 2008 ? did you look at Devart's answer in the link I suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

[GROUP_CONCATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), this is what you have to look at.

Try this;

```
 SELECT EmpID , GROUP_CONCAT(OtherReportID SEPARATOR ', ')
 FROM Emp_tb_Eob_OtherReportingManager GROUP BY DATE(StartDate);
```

**Note**: limitation of 1024 bytes in the resulting column.

**Update for SQL**: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389347/ssrs-group-concat-equivalent-using-an-expression) it's way to do same thing in SQL. Hope it helps..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This **query** will give the **expected result**.

It will also **work in SQL SERVER 2008**

```
SELECT
    T1.EmpID, T1.Status, T1.StartDate , 
    OtherReportId  = 
        stuff((
            SELECT
                ', ' + T2.OtherReportId
            FROM Employee T2
            WHERE
                T2.StartDate = T1.StartDate
            GROUP BY T2.OtherReportId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
        ), 1, 2, '')
FROM Employee T1 GROUP BY T1.StartDate
```